# Moodle required param

Tags: moodle

I was not able to come out of this errorpage:

```
Debug info:
Error code: missingparam

Stack trace:
line 481 of \lib\setuplib.php: moodle_exception thrown
line 548 of \lib\moodlelib.php: call to print_error()
line 31 of \edit_form.php: call to required_param()
```

edit.php:

```
$aroleid = 72; (I could get this value from database)
echo html_writer::div('<a href="'.$CFG->wwwroot.'/edit_form.php?aroleid='.$aroleid.'">'.$org->org_name.'</a>');
```

edit_form.php:

```
 require('config.php');
    require_once($CFG->libdir.'/formslib.php');
    require_once($CFG->libdir.'/adminlib.php');
    $aroleid = required_param('aroleid', PARAM_INT);
    global $DB, $aroleid;
class edit_form extends moodleform 
{    
    function definition()
    {
        global $DB, $aroleid;       
        $mform = $this->_form;  

        $mform->addElement('text', 'roleid');
        $mform->setType('roleid', PARAM_INT);       
        $mform->setDefault('hroleid', $aroleid);

        $this->add_action_buttons();
    }
}

$mform = new edit_form();
if ($mform->is_cancelled()) {
    redirect(new moodle_url('/index.php'));
}                                                                    
else if ($mform->is_submitted()) {
redirect(new moodle_url('/view.php'));
```

I could get parameter aroleid, where submitting the form shows this error and the form is not allowing to redirect to view.php. I was stuck, unable to track the issue going to next level. Would really appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit the form, it includes fields 'roleid' and 'hroleid'.

The form, by default, submits to the current page, but the current page expects there to be a param called 'aroleid' when it loads.

As your form does not include an 'aroleid' field, you get an error, stating that the param is missing.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. I couldn't notice this. My wishes to you Davosmith.